# Let $A ∈ SO(n+1)$ and write $τ(A)$ for the induced map $S^n → S^n$. Prove that $τ(A)\simeq id$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $A ∈ SO(n+1)$ and write $τ(A)$ for the induced map $S^n → S^n$. Prove that $τ(A)\simeq id$ .

My attempt:

So $\tau(A)$ is the map $v \mapsto Av$. So have to construct  a map $H:S^n \times [0,1] \to S^n$.

Since, $S^n$ is path-connected, thus for a fixed $A \in SO(n+1)$, and given $v \in S^n$ , we always have a map $\gamma_v : [0,1] \to S^n$, with $\gamma_v(0)=v$ and $\gamma_v(1)=Av$ and was tempted  to define, $H(v,t):= \gamma_v (t)$, but realized that well-definedness and continuity both are issues!

Tried to modify by picking $\gamma_v$ to be the geodesic joining $v$ and $Av$. But still problem with Continuity and in fact, well-definedness while $v$ and $Av$ are antipodal points! (note that this is always possible since $SO(n+1)$ acts on $S^n$ transitively!)

But got the feeling, that there is some simpler solution looming.

Thanks in Advance for help!

Comment: $SO(n+1)$ is path-connected, and $\tau(I)=id$,

Comment: I get your idea! But can you kindly post a formal answer.

Answer (score 1):

A path $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to SO(n+1)$ such that $\gamma(0)=A$ and $\gamma(1)=I$ will induce a homotopy $\tau\circ\gamma\colon [0,1]\mapsto\text{Maps}(S^n,S^n)$ between $\tau(A)$ and $\tau(I)=id$.  So it suffices to show $SO(n+1)$ is path-connected.

Now there are many ways we can do this.  One way is to use the fact unitary matrices are diagonalisable over $\mathbb{C}$ to yield $A$ is conjugate to a block-diagonal matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I_p\\
&-I_{2q}\\
&&R_{\theta_1}\\
&&&\ddots\\
&&&&R_{\theta_k}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $R_\theta$ is a $2\times 2$ rotation block $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$, $\theta_i\notin\pi\mathbb{Z}$.  It is easy to construct a path from here to the identity in $SO(n+1)$.

Comment: Strictly speaking you also need to prove that $A \mapsto \tau(A)$ is continuous.